# c++ header multiple usage

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class `A` with a type argument `T`.
My program generates several versions for the type argument - `T_1`, .. , `T_N`. Further, for each type `T_i`, the code with `A<T_i>` is compiled into a library `lib_i`. Finally, for each `lib_i`, I call a function from `A<T_i>`. However, I'm always getting result corresponding to `T_1`. What could be the problem?

Here is more detail.

File structure:

- A.hpp
- lib1

  - main1.cpp
  - T1.hpp
  - lib1.so
- lib2

  - main2.cpp
  - T2.hpp
  - lib2.so
- libN

  - mainN.cpp
  - TN.hpp
  - libN.so

Example:

A.hpp:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << T::K << std::endl;
    }
};
```

T1.hpp:

```
class T1
{
    enum { K = 1 };
};
```

T2.hpp:

```
class T2
{
    enum { K = 2 };
};
```

Both main1.cpp and main2.cpp call A::foo().
But the output is always 1.

UPDATE

main1.cpp:

```
#include "../A.hpp"
#include "T1.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A<T1> a;
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

main2.cpp:

```
#include "../A.hpp"
#include "T2.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A<T2> a;
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE2:

This happens on mac os x.

g++ -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc47 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc47 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.7 --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.7 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-stage1-checking --enable-lto --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --disable-ppl-version-check --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.2_2+universal)

However it works correctly on linux.

g++ -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/gcc_4_7/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.0/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/gcc_4_7 --with-gmp=/usr/gcc_4_7 --with-mpfr=/usr/gcc_4_7 --with-mpc=/usr/gcc_4_7 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-4.7
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC)

UPDATE3:

My explanation was misleading because I was actually creating files with the same names (lib1/T.hpp, lib2/T.hpp, .. ). The names of the types T_i were also the same. The correct one was chosen by including T.hpp from the corresponding directory.
Using different names for T_i (not for T_i.hpp) solved the problem. However, I'm still wondering what was wrong when the typenames were the same.

Comment: There is no `A::foo()`. Did you mean `A<T_i>::foo()`?

Comment: @StoryTeller, yes, of course, I wrote it in the text.

Comment: Yes, well, I had to scroll to read the end. :) Anyway, please post main1.cpp and main2.cpp.

Comment: And also, how is each lib_i generated exactly?

Comment: @StoryTeller, for each lib_i, I create a directory using `system("mkdir ..`. Then in each directory, I generate files T.hpp and main.cpp (they actually have the same names, not T1.hpp, T2.hpp etc). I also copy a Makefile into the directory and then I call `system("make -C ..`. Finally, I use `dlopen`, `dlsym` to call the function.

Comment: Are you sure you're generating the headers correctly? Check `dir_2/T.hpp`, and make sure it's really `T2` and not `T1`.

Comment: @Beta, sure, I've checked the header, please see the UPDATE2.

Comment: You say that there is no file called `T2.hpp`, yet the code you post says `#include "T2.hpp"`. And it's still not clear how you're building the libraries or linking them, or to what.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your codes and it works fine. 
`A<T2> a; a.foo()` will output 2.

I am afraid the wrong codes are linked since T.hpp and main.cpp have the same names.

You might want to use **different file names**. :)

Comment: I've just tried it on linux machine, it also works. Please see the UPDATE2.

Comment: Using different file names actually helped ) But I'm still wondering about this strange behavior

Comment: @Nil I am not sure which one caused the problem, the property of you program in different os or the differences between two environments. Maybe you includes the lib1 dir in your program and the compiler will use the T.cpp in lib1 as first choice.